# Why does adding padding to flex item push other elements up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I scroll the range slider to change the spacing(corresponding to change in padding of **img** in this example) the elements above are pushed up. But it works the way as expected when I use "text-align: center" rather than flex box. I wonder why flex item behaves this way. Shouldn't it expand in the opposite direction instead of pushing things up?

```js
const controls = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
      //   const controls = document.querySelectorAll(".controls input")
      const root = document.documentElement;
      const handleChange = function (e) {
        const propertyName = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        const unit = e.target.dataset.unit || "";
        root.style.setProperty(`--${propertyName}`, `${value}${unit}`);
      };
      for (const control of controls) {
        control.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
        control.addEventListener("input", handleChange);
      }
```

```css
 :root {
        --spacing: 10px;
        --blur: 10px;
        --base: #ffc600;
      }
      html {
        font-size: 62.5%;
      }
      body,
      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      p,
      figure,
      picture {
        margin: 0;
      }
      body {
        font-size: 4rem;
        padding-top: 2rem;
        background-color: #193549;
        color: white;
        /* text-align: center; */
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      body > * + * {
        margin-top: 4rem;
      }
      span {
        color: var(--base);
      }
      input[type="range"] {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 10rem;
      }
      input[type="color"] {
        width: 10rem;
      }
      img {
        padding: var(--spacing);
        background: var(--base);
        filter: blur(var(--blur));
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Update CSS Variables with <span>JS</span></h1>
    <div class="controls">
      <label for="">Spacing:</label>
      <input
        name="spacing"
        class="control"
        type="range"
        min="10"
        max="200"
        value="10"
        data-unit="px"
      />
      <label for="">Blur:</label>
      <input
        name="blur"
        class="control"
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="25"
        value="10"
        data-unit="px"
      />
      <label for="">Base Color:</label>
      <input name="base" class="control" type="color" value="#f6b73c" />
    </div>
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/7bwQXzbF6KE/800x500" alt="image" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove flex-direction: column; */ from your body in your css and add: flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: It solves the problem! Thank you. I will delete this post since there is already a similar question asked